# OpenGL TCS — limits on size of per-patch array

Tags: opengl, shader, tessellation

I'm somewhat confused about using arrays as **per-patch** variables in the TCS (and TES) of the OpenGL pipeline. The basic TCS example below works, but as soon as I increase the size of `anotherTest` to something above `32`, I get

```
0(5) : error C5041: cannot locate suitable resource to bind variable "anotherTest". Possibly large array.
```

Using `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TESS_PATCH_COMPONENTS, &maxPatchComponents)` in my C++ code (in a Qt 5.10 framework on Linux) I get

```
:: Using OpenGL 4.3.0 NVIDIA 396.24
 → maxPatchComponents = 120
```

Therefore, I'd say that I should be able to use even `anotherTest[120]` (note that `gl_TessLevelOuter` and `gl_TessLevelInner` do not count towards the number of patch components). So, what is going on? I know that `32` is the common limit for `GL_MAX_PATCH_VERTICES` (also on my machine), but that should not interfere with the size of my per-patch variable. Thoughts?

---

```
#version 430
// Tessellation control shader

layout (vertices = 4) out;

patch out int anotherTest[32];

void main(void) {

  if (gl_InvocationID == 0) {
    gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 1;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 64;
  }

  anotherTest[0] = 2;

  gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
}
```

Comment: "*OpenGL 4.3.0 NVIDIA 396.24*" Have you considered upgrading your NVIDIA driver? Unless they're no longer supporting your hardware, your driver version really ought to be more recent.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is the latest version (see e.g. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=NVIDIA-396.24-Linux-Driver). I choose to use OpenGL 4.3 instead of 4.5 or 4.6 because of some MESA issues when I run this code on another machine.